# Animate Counter on Scroll Past Part of Div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a counter section on my site which animates on page load, however I am trying to trigger the animation when the user gets to that section.

Currently I have this, however the animation only triggers when the div is beyond the nav, ie: the top of the screen including the nav. How would I change this so that the animation triggers as the div becomes visible?

I'm also having an issue that it shows to start as the full number without the commas, and then goes to 0 and animates, how can I make it show a 0 to begin with?

I'm pretty new to JS so would appreciate any explanation into this.

Heres what I have:

```js
const convert = str => {
  // Find the number
  let regx = /(\d{1,3})(\d{3}(?:,|$))/;
  // Set a variable
  let currStr;
  // Start loop
  do {
    // Replace current string, split it
    currStr = (currStr || str.split(`.`)[0])
      .replace(regx, `$1,$2`)
  } while (currStr.match(regx)); // Loop

  // Return our result from function
  return (str.split(`.`)[1]) ?
    currStr.concat(`.`, str.split(`.`)[1]) :
    currStr;
};

$(window).scroll(startCounter);

function startCounter() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#counter').offset().top) {
    $(window).off("scroll", startCounter);
    $('.count').each(function() {
      $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
      }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function(now) {
          $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
          $(this).text(convert($(this).text()))
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.section-counter {
  margin-top: 150vh;
  margin-bottom: 150vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section-counter" id="counter">

  <div class="row">
    <h2>Headline Data Figures</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col span-1-of-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="shiva"><span class="count">1688019</span>
          <h3>Contributions</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="shiva"><span class="count">82150</span>
        <h3>Items of Business</h3>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col span-1-of-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="shiva"><span class="count">10505</span>
          <h3>Meetings</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="shiva"><span class="count">168260</span>
        <h3>Written&#47;Oral Questions</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row arrow-dark arrow__7 animated pulse infinite">
    <i class="ion-md-arrow-dropdown"></i>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that you're comparing the offset of the div to the *top* of the screen, when actually you'd want to find out where the bottom of the screen is, and compare that to the position of the div.

Regarding starting from `0`, you can have the elements use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to determine the max instead of the text, that way you can have the elements read `0` until they start counting:

```js
const convert = str => {
  // Find the number
  let regx = /(\d{1,3})(\d{3}(?:,|$))/;
  // Set a variable
  let currStr;
  // Start loop
  do {
    // Replace current string, split it
    currStr = (currStr || str.split(`.`)[0])
      .replace(regx, `$1,$2`)
  } while (currStr.match(regx)); // Loop

  // Return our result from function
  return (str.split(`.`)[1]) ?
    currStr.concat(`.`, str.split(`.`)[1]) :
    currStr;
};

$(window).scroll(startCounter);

function startCounter() {
  var bottomOfScreen = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();
  if (bottomOfScreen > $('#counter').offset().top) {
    $(window).off("scroll", startCounter);
    $('.count').each(function() {
      $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).attr('data-max')
      }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function(now) {
          $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
          $(this).text(convert($(this).text()))
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.section-counter {
  margin-top: 150vh;
  margin-bottom: 150vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section-counter" id="counter">

  <div class="row">
    <h2>Headline Data Figures</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col span-1-of-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="shiva"><span class="count" data-max="1688019">0</span>
          <h3>Contributions</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="shiva"><span class="count" data-max="812150">0</span>
        <h3>Items of Business</h3>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col span-1-of-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="shiva"><span class="count" data-max="10505">0</span>
          <h3>Meetings</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="shiva"><span class="count" data-max="168260">0</span>
        <h3>Written&#47;Oral Questions</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row arrow-dark arrow__7 animated pulse infinite">
    <i class="ion-md-arrow-dropdown"></i>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: This works great, it starts a bit too soon however, can you guide me a little in where to change for this?

Comment: Actually, its alright I figured that part out, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I will give you the logic to kickstart an animation once the user gets to an element.

The relevant event trigger is the ONMOUSEOVER, so to incorporate it...

```
 <div id="abc" onmouseover="AnimateIt();"></div>
```

Needless to mention that our element must have its animation PAUSED in its styling to begin with, like this...

```
  animation-play-state:paused;
```

So the JavaScript logic to animate...

```
 function AnimateIt(){ abc.style.animationPlayState='running'; }
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks, howeber I'm not looking for a mouseover trigger. I already have the scrollTop working, but looking to trigger before it hits the top of the screen. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Yy6r6/422/

Comment: You said "I am trying to trigger the animation when the user gets to that section" and that's EXACTLY what I gave you.

Comment: I added top - $('nav').height() and that seemed to achieve more what I'm after. However counter still not beginning at 0.

Comment: Sorry, I don't do 3rd party $... I only do javascript proper. Thanks and good luck.

Comment: I'm unsure how this answers the original question. Your animation doesn't seem to do anything, simple setting an animation play state won't cause the text to count upward

Comment: That's for her to supply. I've demonstrated automatic start/pause on mouseover.